# When bulding a CNN, I am getting complaints from Keras that do not make sense to me.

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

My input shape is supposed to be 100x100. It represents a sentence. Each word is a vector of 100 dimensions and there are 100 words at maximum in a sentence.

I feed eight sentences to the CNN.I am not sure whether this means my input shape should be 100x100x8 instead.

Then the following lines

```
Convolution2D(10, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                       input_shape=(100, 100))
```

complains:

Input 0 is incompatible with layer convolution2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

This does not make sense to me as my input dimension is 2. I can get through it by changing input_shape to (100,100,8). But the "expected ndim=4" bit just does not make sense to me.

I also cannot see why a convolution  layer of 3x3 with 10 filters do not accept input of 100x100.

Even I get thru the complains about the "expected ndim=4". I run into problem in my activation layer. There it complains:

Cannot apply softmax to a tensor that is not 2D or 3D. Here, ndim=4

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how to fix it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and I solved it adding one dimension for `channel` to `input_shape` argument.

I suggest following solution:

```
Convolution2D(10, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(100, 100, 1))
```

Comment: its not working for me can you suggest  to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499346/error-when-checking-input-expected-conv2d-1-input-to-have-4-dimensions-but-got

Comment: why do you need a channel? this is because of Keras/Tensorflow requirement?

Answer (score 9):

the missing dimension for 2D convolutional layers is the "channel" dimension.

For image data, the channel dimension is 1 for grayscale images and 3 for color images.

In your case, to make sure that Keras won't complain, you could use 2D convolution with 1 channel, or 1D convolution with 100 channels.

Ref: http://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d

Answer (score 0):

Keras's Convolutional layer takes in 4 dimensional arrays, so you need to structure your input to fit it that way. The dimensions are made up of `(batch_size,x_dim,y_dim,channels)`. This makes a lot of sense in the case of images, which is where CNNs are mostly used, but for your case it gets a bit trickier.

However, `batch_size` is invariant to the dataset so you need to stack the 8 sentences in the first dimension to get `(8,100,100)`. Channels can be kept to 1 and you need to write it in such a way that keras will accept the data, so expanding the data to `(8,100,100,1)` would be the input shape you need.