# Dimension error for convolution2d in keras for text classification

Tags: keras, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, conv-neural-network

My input shape is a 10000x500 text document. 10000 represents number of documents and 500 represents number of words.

What I am trying to do is to feed the text for kera's embedding, followed by BLSTM, and then followed by Conv2D and then 2Dpooling, flatten and finally a fully connected dense layer.

Architecture is shown as below:

```
inp = Input(shape=(500,))
x = Embedding(max_features=10000, embed_size=100)(inp)
x = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(50, return_sequences=True))(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(100,500,1))(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
```

The output shape from the embedding would be (None, 500, 100)
The output shape from BLSTM's hidden state would be (None, 500, 100).
I would like a Conv2D to extract local features over hidden layers from BLSTM. However, I'm having dimension discrepancy error.

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_8: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3
```

I have tried a solution here [When bulding a CNN, I am getting complaints from Keras that do not make sense to me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085653/when-bulding-a-cnn-i-am-getting-complaints-from-keras-that-do-not-make-sense-to?rq=1) but still getting the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

a) Use `Conv2D` with `rows=100`, `cols=500` and `channels=1` by adding a dimension to `x`:

```
x = Lambda(lambda t: t[..., None])(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(100,500,1))(x)
```

b) Use `Conv1D` with `steps=100` and `input_dim=500`, and use `MaxPooling1D`:

```
x = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(100, 500))(x)
x = MaxPooling1D()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
```

Comment: what does the lambda function actually do to the shape?

Comment: It adds one dimension at the last axis. It is equivalent to https://keras.io/backend/#expand_dims with axis=-1